# Negative ramifications of "ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.None" in C# web services

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm adding a method overload to an asmx web service written in C#, and in order to publish it I need to change the WebServiceBinding attribute of the service to the above.  Doing so seems pretty harmless (the web service will only be consumed by applications written in house, at least in the foreseeable future), but am I missing some implications of that choice?

Comment: What's a "C# web service"? C# is a nice programming language, but I didn't think it included web services.

Comment: Also, did you mean ASMX web services, or WCF?

Comment: edited above, and hopefully clarified

Comment: @cori: Did you reach any conclusion regarding this? If so, would you mind posting it here?

Comment: @Niklas;

No real conclusion. Well, that is to say I concluded that this is an internal-only web-service and in this case worrying too much about the implications of this choice amounted to micro-optimization. I went with what made it work (WsiProfiles.None). 

I did do a little more research after that and determined that as long as my consumers are well-defined and no one is going to be generating a proxy from the WSDL of my service the WSI Profile conformity is not pertinent.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to wrap things up here (after @Niklas's query), I decided that worrying too much about this on an internal-only web service amounted to micro-optimization.

Specifically, I determined that as long as no one is going to generate a proxy from my WSDL for the service and as long as all of the consumers are well-known (and in this case under my control), the WS-I profile I conform to is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
To implement method overloading in webservices first you must set the MessageName
attribute of your webservice then set your webservice binding ConformsTo 
attribute to WsiProfiles.None and that’s it! Note that you can do second step 
in your Web.Config file for all webservices.
```

([according to this blog post](http://nayyeri.net/blog/Method-overloading-in-webservices/)).

Comment: That post was among my research into the question.  To clarify, I have no problem getting it to work; the web service is running just fine.  The question that I haven't been able to find a definitive answer to is whether there are some implications of using WsiProfile.None that I should consider - nothing I've found talks about what that choice means to the usability of a web service.